# How to make a cumulative distribution function of the log-normal distribution on excel?

Tags: probability, functions, computer-science, normal-distribution

I would like to program or make on my own a cumulative distribution function of the log-normal distribution on a computer. How to do it ? is it possible on excel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula =NORM.DIST((LOG(X)-MEAN)/VAR,0,1,TRUE), replacing X, MEAN and VAR with the appropriate values or cell references.